Regex split where \# splits and \\# does not
I need to split some text but \\ means a single \ and \ is an indicator for a literal character.  I have started with the following code but it is fooled by \\.   so \# (# preceded by 0 or an even number of 's ) would split but # (# preceded by odd number of 's ) would not split
string message = @"1#2\\#3#3\#still 3#4\\\# still 4";
var v = Regex.Split(message, @"(?<!\\)#")
        .ToArray();

I would like the message to come out as
1
2\\
3\#still 3
4\\\# still 4

but cannot figure out how to ignore the \\ instances so mine comes out as
1
2\\#3
3\#still 3
4\\\# still 4


This looks like C#. Please add the language tag.

Your input string has three times a "3", while your output only has two of them. Where did the third one go?

In the desired result you have removed the slash before #, but not before \. Why is that?

Sorry I missed some slashes, essentially keep \ and # but split on solitary # so \# (# preceded by even number of )
and would split but # (# preceded by odd number of ) would not

What about the number of "3"?

It will be easier to do this with Matches than with Split, as you can then pair as many escaping slashes with the subsequent character as needed:
    var v = Regex.Matches(message, @"(\\.|[^#])+")
                  .Cast<Match>()
                  .Select(m => m.Value)
                  .ToArray();

Make sure to include using System.Linq;

I think by using a double look back it works. so changeing the regex string to
@"(?<!(?<![^\]\(?:\{2}){0,10})\)#")
string message = @"(?<!(?<![^\\]\\(?:\\{2}){0,10})\\)#");
var v = Regex.Split(message, @"(?<!\\)#")
    .ToArray();

this gives an output of
   1
   2\\
   3
   3\#still 3
   4\\\# still 4


You are replacing the input string with a regular expression? What have you done to message?

Also, the limit of {0,10} does not make it generic.

Be aware that this does not work for \\#A: according to the rules, a split should happen at #.
